# Was bedeutet "andere Feldpostnummer"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, meaning-in-context

Ich bin schon öfter über die Wendung "Leute von der anderen Feldpostnummer" gestolpert, weiß sie aber bis heute nicht richtig einzuordnen. Eine ursprünglich militärische Herkunft wäre wohl naheliegend, ist mir aber nicht bekannt.

Was also bedeutet diese Wendung, und was ist die Herkunft?

Comment: ein Beispiel mit Kontext gibts [hier](http://blasphemieblog2.wordpress.com/skala-fur-glaubensintensitat/) bei Punkt 9

Comment: Kein sehr schmeichelhaftes Beispiel...^^

Comment: Advice for non-native speakers: Don't use this phrase in conversations unless you're really sure the context is right. (See below why.)

Comment: Ich hätte auch noch ein anderes Beispiel, das war allerdings noch _offensiver_, weswegen ich es auch nicht verlinkt habe. Das oben verlinkte Beispiel hatte ich neulich erst gefunden und deswegen dann die Frage gestellt.

Comment: Es kommt vollkommen auf den Kontext an. Ich würde aber vermuten, dass der Ausdruck in den meisten Fällen synonym zu "vom anderen Ufer" gebraucht wird.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Laut [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feldpostnummer) stammt die Wendung aus dem zweiten Weltkrieg und steht für die gegnerische Seite.

> In der Landsersprache wurden gegnerische Soldaten scherzhaft als "Kollegen von der anderen Feldpostnummer" bezeichnet.

einem Google-Überblick über die ersten paar Seiten zufolge wird sie heutzutage von Weltkriegs-Nostalgikern, im Wehrsport, auffällig häufig aber auch in der Neonazi-Szene verwendet, z.B. vom [DVU](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVU)-Gründer [Gerhard Frey](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerhard_Frey_%28Politiker%29). (Google nach "andere Feldpostnummer" - das meiste ist von Nazis).

Aber auch im Polit-Mainstream ist der Begriff bekannt, z.B. [zu Guttenberg:](http://www.csu-main-spessart.de/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=107%3akarl-theodor-zu-guttenberg-lockt-1500-besucher)

> Der Minister streifte dabei sowohl bundespolitische Themen, wusste aber auch mit Informationen aus der Region zu überzeugen. »Ich bin nicht so spät, weil ich in ihr Schecherloch gefallen bin«, brachte die Zuhörer ebenso zum Lachen wie die Bemerkung, dass Hausherr Klaus Hofmann »offensichtlich eine andere Feldpostnummer habe«. Er überzeugte mit klaren Ansagen und der Forderung, »nicht nach Umfragwerten zu schauen, sondern in der Lage zu sein etwas zu tun.

(Bin nicht sicher, in welchem Kontext das hier gemeint ist - Klaus Hofmann ist jedoch Bürgermeister der besuchten Stadt und Mitglied der Freien Wähler (FW), wahrscheinlich bezieht es sich darauf.) und [auch](http://www.tagblatt.de/Home/nachrichten_artikel,-Nach-der-verkorksten-Praesidentenwahl-wird-das-Gegrummel-in-der-Koalition-lauter-_arid,105057_print,1.html)

> FDP-Verteidigungsexpertin Elke Hoff wies "auf die andere Feldpostnummer", also Dissidenten bei CDU und CSU, Ex-Verteidigungsminister Franz Josef Jung (CDU) sprach von einer "allgemeinen Unzufriedenheit" mit Schwarz-Gelb.

Comment: Autsch, was für ein böser Kontext. Fällt wohl in eine Kategorie mit "bis zur Vergasung hetzen" und "Bombenwetter"... -_-

Comment: Hui, Google liefert bei _Schecherloch_ nur 8 Treffer, einer davon ist diese Frage. Ich nehme mal an es ist eine regional bekannte Schlucht oder Höle gemeint.

Comment: Leute, Soldaten bezeichnen sich nicht als Kollegen. Nicht einmal den Feind. Höchstens als Verteidigungskollegen - aber das kann nur nachvollziehen wer die Bw zwischen ~89 und ~2003 erlebt hat. Also: nicht die "Kollegen von der anderen Feldpostnummer". Sondern "Kameraden". Und das ist ganz neutral gemeint, vergesst mal kurz die Leute die das Wort hijacken für ihren Neo-schmarrn.